# How can I keep Link and IconButton on the same line?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a link with a long text and a "copy" icon after it. I don't want the icon to be ever rendered on a separate line alone.

So these should be ok:

[image]

[image]

But not this:

[image]

The basic code is:

```
<>
 <Link>cat dog cow pig owl rabbit hare wolf fox</Link>
 <IconButton><EditIcon/></IconButton>
</>
```

I can easily place the icon to the right with a flexbox, but not sure how I effectively insert a non-breaking space between a text and an icon.

Comment: Those are both presumably inline or inline-block elements, so just put them on the same line in your code. Otherwise you'll need to style them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how to do it, hence the question :)

Comment: _Put them in the same line of your code_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem and I managed to solve it using [MUI's Grid](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/).
I had to do some string splitting in my case, so I included here as well. Hope this helps!

```
<Link onClick={() => { alert('test'); }}>
  <Grid container direction="row" alignItems="center">
    <Grid item>
      <Typography variant="body1">
        {linkText.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ')}
      </Typography>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item>
      <Typography variant="body1" display="flex" alignItems="center">
        {linkText.split(' ').slice(-1)}
        <IconButton>
          <EditIcon
            onClick={(event) => {
              event?.stopPropagation();
              // do stuff
            }}
          />
        </IconButton>
      </Typography>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Link>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's great. 
For some reason  `e.stopPropagation()` did not work for me, I had to use  `e.preventDefault()`